# Swift, This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key "array"

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am developing popover controller and while opening the popover I am transferring the Array (properties) to the popoverController (SortingPopoverController).For view I have s created popView.xib and in firstOwner, I have attached the "SortingPopovercontroller".

### My code below

```
    func sortingPressed(sender: AnyObject){
            var sortingPopView = SortingPopoverController(nibName: "PopView",bundle: nil )

     var sortingPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sortingPopView)

      sortingPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 100)


      sortingPopoverController.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sortingBtn, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
       , animated: true)

      sortingPopoverController.setValue(properties, forKey: "properties") //i am passing this array to the "sorting controller"

  }
```

///Sorting controller code

```
    class SortingPopoverController: UIViewController
        {
            var properties:[Property] = [Property]()
            var propertyNameSrt = false
            var addressSrt = false
            var ascSorting = false
            var utility = Utility()

             override func viewDidLoad()
                {
                     super.viewDidLoad()

                     let propertyNameSorting = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "propertyNameSorting:")
                      self.propertyNameView.addGestureRecognizer(propertyNameSorting)

                     let addressSorting = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addressSorting:")
                     self.addressNameView.addGestureRecognizer(addressSorting)
                     imgTickPropertyName.hidden = true
                     imgTickAddress.hidden = true

                     properties = self.valueForKey("properties") as! [Property]
                     println(properties.count)

                }
        }
```

on view did load i am getting error as "**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key properties**"

Comment: which line give error

Comment: What is intended by `properties = self.valueForKey("properties") as! [Property]`?

Comment: @Memon... sortingPopoverController.setValue(properties, forKey: "properties") //i am passing this array to the "sorting controller" ......................line gives an eror

Comment: @JefferyThomas...it will fetch the set object of "properties"..i assume..........properties = self.valueForKey("properties") as! [Property]

Comment: `self.valueForKey("properties")` returns the same object as `self.properties`, so you are saying `properties = properties as! [Property]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortingPopoverController` is a `UIPopoverController`. You meant to use `sortingPopView`, with is a `SortingPopoverController`.

```
sortingPopView.setValue(properties, forKey: "properties") //i am passing this array to the "sorting controller"
```

---

There shouldn't be a need for the [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) syntax here.

```
sortingPopView.properties = properties
```

will do the same thing. Note: the above will also be type safe so if `sortingPopView.properties` and `properties` are of different types, you will get a warning or error.

Comment: thats perfect! but i am getting 0 as count in the  array...in popover controller..Please advise?

Comment: is it beacuse i am initilizing the array like (var properties:[Property] = [Property]())?

Comment: anyways...u have given answer of my questions...so you deserved +1..thanks

Comment: @dhavalshah I don't know why `properties.count == 0`. Are you sure `properties.count > 0` in `func sortingPressed()`?